# Why this is not Working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
.......
........

key1 = 'start' + i + '';
key2 = 'end' + i + '';
datePass.push({
    key1: start,
    key2: end
});
```

it returns

```
[{key1 : `somevalue`, key1: 'somevalue'}]
```

but i want

```
[{start1 : `somevalue`, end1: 'somevalue'}]
```

and so on.

How can i do so. pleas help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object-literal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using:

```
datePass[key1] = 'some value';
datePass[key2] = 'some other value';
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var i=1;
var key1 = 'start' + i;
var key2 = 'end' + i;
var datePass = {}; // this instantiates a blank object
datePass[key1] = 'someValue'; // assigns a value to object key
datePass[key2] = 'someValue';
```

Answer (score 1):

IF your goal is to create a list of `{startx: xxx, endx: xxx}` **object** s , since you're using push:
you've to proceed in the following way.

```
key1 = 'start' + i;
key2 = 'end' + i;

var o = {};
o[key1] = start;
o[key2] = end;

datePuss.push(o);
```