# Set value to non existing object

Tags: javascript

Say i have this object:

```
test = {
    testObj: {
        "1": {
            "key": "value"
        }
    }
}
```

And i want to add values to `testObj` like so:

```
test.testObj["2"].key = "my value";
```

I get error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'key' of undefined`

Now i do understand that `key` does not exist yet, but `2` doesn't exist also, and yet i can set value to it:

`test.testObj["2"] = "something";`

So what can i do about it?

**EDIT**
wow i feel stupid for not figuring that out by myself... anyways thank you guys.

Comment: Check below link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object-literal

Comment: @Linas don't feel stupid... but _do_ mark an answer. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript doesn't know what `test.testObj["2"]` should be in this scenario, so it ends up testing it as an existing property:

```
test.testObj["2"].key = "my value";
```

The assignment can only apply to the last part of the structure on the left.

But you can tell it what it is by creating the object first:

```
test.testObj["2"]={};
test.testObj["2"].key = "my value";
```

Or in a single step:

```
test.testObj["2"] = { key: "my value"};
```