# Does JavaScript hoist if statements when object literals are involved?

Tags: javascript, callback, conditional-statements, object-literal, hoisting

```js
var foo = {}; 
document.body.innerHTML = console.log = location.hash = 'Hi ' + '<br>  ' + foo.bar + '<br>  ' + foo.baz; 

setTimeout(function()
           {
  foo.baz = foo["bar"] = []; 
  foo.bar.push(new Date); 
  foo.baz.push(new Date); 
  document.body.innerHTML = console.log = location.hash = 'Hi ' + '<br>  ' + foo.bar + '<br>  ' + foo.baz}, 
           5000);
```

Comment: It should work. The 'if' fails because the end result is 'falsy'. But this is surely valid in js.

Comment: The condition was made up, but I've had this experience more than once when the method in question is called after an AJAX request.

Comment: Could you show a concrete example, a working demo on jsfiddle maybe?

Comment: Not right now. If the problem persists, that's the next logical step.

Comment: AJAX... asynchronous... yada, yada, yada

Comment: If it has to do with the asynchronous nature of the call, how does declaring the keys statically versus dynamically fix the problem?

Comment: First, I have no idea if it has to do with the async nature of the call, because you've not given an example of what "it" actually is. That said, as far as I know, you're creating the object, making the AJAX call, updating the object in the callback, but trying to log the new properties outside the callback. I'm not clear on what the debugger's display of properties has to do with your `if` statement though.

Comment: When I update the object, then try to access them immediately afterwards, they are not showing up in the object when I step through the code. So the question is why are they `undefined` at this point, as noted in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you set `node.bar` equal to `false`, `(node.foo && node.bar)` will evaluate to `false` whether the properties are attached or not. Rather than checking if those properties are `true`, you should check whether they are undefined:

```
if (typeof node.foo !== 'undefined' && typeof node.bar !== 'undefined') 
{ 
  ...
} 
else 
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it may be implementation dependent:

> The object that may be created in step 1 is not accessible outside of the above method. An implementation might choose to avoid the actual creation of the object. The only situation where such an actual property access that uses this internal method can have visible effect is when it invokes an accessor function.

So instead of accessing the property, stringify and pass by value.

**References**

- [ECMAScript-5: Section 8.7.2 Note](https://es5.github.io/#x8.7.2)