# Javascript setter and getter with key for object

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object in a variable  `var o={};`
I want to do something like what `.push()` method doing in array for my object.

JS code:

```
// Array:
var ar=[];
ar.push('omid');
ar.push('F');
var got=ar[1];
// above code is standard but not what I'm looking for !
/*-------------------------------------*/


// Object:
var obj={};

/*  obj.push('key','value'); // I want do something like this
    var got2=obj.getVal('key'); // And this
*/
```

Is this possible at all ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object-literal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Object-Literals use a `Key->Value` model, there is no JS *method* to "push" a value.

You can either use Dot Notation:

```
var Obj = {};

Obj.foo = "bar";

console.log(Obj);
```

Or Bracket Notation:

```
var Obj = {},
    foo = "foo";

Obj[foo]   = "bar";
Obj["bar"] = "foo";

console.log(Obj);
```

Consider reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects, as arming yourself with this knowledge will be invaluable in the future.

Answer (score 4):

```
var obj = {}

// use this if you are hardcoding the key names
obj.key = 'value'
obj.key // => 'value'

// use this if you have strings with the key names in them
obj['key2'] = 'value'
obj['key2'] // => 'value'

// also use the second method if you have keys with odd names
obj.! = 'value' // => SyntaxError
obj['!'] = 'value' // => OK
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some javascript magic that makes it work.
Take a look.

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj,'push',{
 value:function(x,y){
  this[x]=y;
 }
});

obj.push('name','whattttt');  <<<this works!!!

obj;
//{name:'whattttt'}
obj.name or obj['name']..
//whattttt
```

The reason i defined **.push** function using Object.defineProperty because i didn't want it to show up as a property of object. So if you have 3 items in object this would have always been the 4th one. And mess up the loops always. However, using this method. You can make properties hidden but accessible.

Though i don't know why you would use this method when there is already a easy way to do it.

to assign a value do this

```
obj.variable = 'value';
```

if value key is number or weird do this...

```
obj[1] = 'yes';
```

to access number or weird name you also do that

```
obj[1];
```

and finally to assign random keys or key that has been generated in code, not hard coded, than use this form too.

```
var person= 'him';

obj[him]='hello';
```