# Not getting json the way I want

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to send or retrieve, not sure where the fault is, in a specific way...

Here is how it should look when using JSON.stringify(test):

```
{"1":"<div class=\"test\">test1</div>","2":"<div class=\"test\">test2</div>","1":"<div class=\"test\">test1</div>"}
```

But my ajax/json return looks like this:

```
["'1':'<div class='test'>test1</div>'","'2':'<div class='test'>test2</div>'","'3':'<div class='test'>test3</div>'"]
```

I need curly brackets at the beginning and " not to be there.

Here is how I send and get data.

test.php

```
$test = array();

$test[] = array('id' => '1', 'name' => 'test1');
$test[] = array('id' => '2', 'name' => 'test2');
$test[] = array('id' => '3', 'name' => 'test3');

echo json_encode($test);
```

And the javascript which retrieves it:

```
var mytest = [];

$.getJSON('test.php', function(data){ 

    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
        mytest.push("'"+val.id+"':'<div class='test'>"+val.name+"</div>'");
    });

    alert(JSON.stringify(mytest));

});
```

Really hoping for help... I am stuck. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You are creating an array, and expect it to start with `{`? that simply won't happen. arrays start with `[` in javascript.

Comment: So what I am trying to accomplish can't be done?

Comment: It can be done, it just wouldn't be very useful as an array. If you wanted an array, you should just keep what you already have in `data` as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JavaScript code, you're creating an array in your results instead of an object... So instead of using `[]`, you should use `{}` and instead of using .push, you should directly assign the attributes of the object with `mytest["1"] = whatever`. So here's a modified form of your code...

```
var mytest = {};

$.getJSON('test.php', function(data){ 

    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
        mytest[val.id] = '<div class="test">'+val.name+'</div>';
    });

    alert(JSON.stringify(mytest));

});
```

Comment: Just perfect... Just what I was looking for ;-)

Answer (score 2):

you're using an array.  As Kevin noted, that won't work.  you need to declare an object literal which expects key value pairs.

ie

```
var myTest = {}; 

$.each(data, function (i, val) {
  mytest[i] = val;
});
```

This is a good and more detailed explanation.  [How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object-literal)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely what you really want is just an object.

```
var mytest = {};
$.each(data, function (i, val) {
    mytest[val.id] = "<div class='test'>"+val.name+"</div>";
})
```

Note, i purposely moved `var mytest` into the ajax callback because there's no reason to define it outside (it won't be useable outside of the callback)