# finding available combinations (permutations?) of two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Having a hard time googling for this since I'm not sure what the concepts are called, and all of the "combinations of two arrays/groups" SO posts are not giving me the output I would expect.

Example arrays:

```
var array1 = ['Bob', 'Tina'];
var array2 = [0, 100];
```

I can find possible combinations with nested looping through both arrays. But that would give me an output like:

```
var array1 = ['Bob', 'Tina'];
var array2 = [0, 100];
var options = []

array1.forEach(function (name) {
  array2.forEach(function (number) {
    options.push([name, number])
  })
})


console.log(options);
> [ [ 'Bob', 0 ], [ 'Bob', 100 ], [ 'Tina', 0 ], [ 'Tina', 100 ] ]
```

this post ([Creating Combinations in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822950/creating-combinations-in-javascript)) gives me the output above

But what I'm really looking for would give me arrangements/combinations like this:

```
[
  [['Bob', 0], ['Tina', 0]],
  [['Bob', 0], ['Tina', 100]],
  [['Bob', 100], ['Tina', 0]],
  [['Bob', 100], ['Tina', 100]]
]
```

And it would need to be able to scale with longer arrays, but 2x2 is the easiest example.

This cartesian example here ([Matrix combinations of two arrays in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478829/matrix-combinations-of-two-arrays-in-javascript)) also gave me broken out strings and not correlated arrangements:

```
[ { '0': 'B', '1': 'o', '2': 'b' },
  { '0': 'B', '1': 'o', '2': 'b' },
  { '0': 'T', '1': 'i', '2': 'n', '3': 'a' },
  { '0': 'T', '1': 'i', '2': 'n', '3': 'a' } ]
```

I have been looking through google and SO but I'm hitting roadblocks because I'm not sure what I'm actually looking for.

Comment: Some form of iterating through both arrays is how you would do this, but you need to show what you have tried so far.  See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Combinations in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822950/creating-combinations-in-javascript)

Comment: I recommend doing it by hand with different inputs, and looking for patterns that you can utilize. As a programmer, making at least a good attempt is in your job description.

Comment: Edited to include more info and more links to solutions I've tried. My problem isn't just making combinations but creating possible options where I can get arrangements like `[['Bob', 0], ['Tina',0]]`

Comment: What I notice is that you need double permutations. First create a set of every possible element in the second array with each element in the first array, and they find all combinations of THOSE permutations

Comment: Ahhhh ok, that sounds it might be it, I'll try that.

Comment: This ended up making me wish I knew more number theory :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this might help you to get your actual combination:

```js
var array1 = ['Bob', 'Tina'];
var array2 = [0, 100];
var resultArray = []

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
    var tempArray = [];
    tempArray.push(array1[i]);
    tempArray.push(array2[j]);
    resultArray.push(tempArray);
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
    var tempArray = [];
    tempArray.push(array1[j]);
    tempArray.push(array2[i]);
    resultArray.push(tempArray);
  }
}

console.log(resultArray);
```

Comment: Thanks, this did give me the output I was looking for, and it sounds like the concept someone mentioned above, finding combination options, and then finding combinations of those combinations.

Comment: or very close at least, I think this + knowing to look for double permutations gives me enough to run with.

Comment: Glad to know that it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem, but don't know how efficient it is - I'll bet there's much better ways of doing it.

```js
var array1 = ['Bob', 'Tina', 'Sam'];
var array2 = [0, 100, 200];

var resultCount = Math.pow(array2.length, array1.length);
var results = new Array(resultCount);
for(var i = 0; i < resultCount; i++) {
    results[i] = new Array(array1.length);
}

for(var row = 0; row < resultCount; row++) {
    for(var column = 0; column < array1.length; column++) {
        var result = row * array1.length + column;
        var category = array1.length * Math.pow( array2.length, array1.length - 1 - column);
        var idx = ~~(result / category) % array2.length;
        results[row][column] = [ array1[column], array2[idx] ];
 }
}
console.log(results);
```

I think you could actually do this in terms of number/string manipulation by thinking of array2 as a radix (each value maps to a digit) and array1 as the number of digits.  As long as array2 has 36 or less elements you could convert every number from 0 up to the number of combinations as a string (`Number.toString(radix)`) and then convert each char from the resulting string back to an index into your arrays.

Comment: This is the exact algorithm the OP said didn't solve their problem.

Comment: @4castle not any more :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some hints that you might find helpful. First, I assume you know how to iterate over an array:

```
var array1 = ['Bob', 'Tina'];

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    // you can access the ith element  using array1[i]
     // for example:
    alert(array1[i]);
}
```

I also assume you know how to execute nested looping:

```
var array1 = ['Bob', 'Tina'];
var array2 = [0, 100];

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
        alert(array1[i] + " " + array2[j]):
    }
}
```

What you may be missing is how to construct a new array:

```
var five = 5;
var six = 6;

var myArray = [five, six];
```

You also may be missing the ability to push a new array onto an existing "master" array:

```
var five = 5;
var six = 6;
var masterArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    masterArray.push([five, six]);
}
```

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: Thanks, and I have edited my post based on other feedback to include options like this that I have tried.

Comment: The nested loop + pushing options to a master array gives me possible combinations like

`> [ [ 'Bob', 0 ], [ 'Bob', 100 ], [ 'Tina', 0 ], [ 'Tina', 100 ] ]`

but I need to find all combinations including ones where Bob and Tina can get the same value.

Comment: The same principles are at play, but you will need 3 layers of looping.