# Console.log: the length of array is 0 and 1 at same time

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

About the console.log, i believe i have a case related to

[Javascript array length of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44433131/javascript-array-length-of-0)

In my console i got

[image]

my code related at 24

```
const lists = this.props.localData.lists;
if(lists.length === 0 ) {
  console.log('lists',lists);
}
```

What is going on here?

if it is right in its way, how could i access `lists[0]`(undefined)?

could anyone give me a hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The *console* object is implementation dependent, it's not necessarily consistent.

Comment: your first element starts at index zero

Comment: rule #1 - the console lies - hover over the blue `i`

Comment: Well, the linked question's answer is probably valid here, too. So you need to inspect the code following the console.log call and see if the element is added there. You can use the debugger for that.

Comment: Your array had a length of 0 at the moment it was logged, but at the moment you are looking at the log, it has length 1.

Comment: @JLRishe But it shouldn't happen if we try to print the array again in the console, should it? I see `Array(0)` no matter what I do.

Comment: you only log the array if its length is zero, so the only output in the console would be when the array has length zero - subsequent changes to the array will be "visible" in the console because that's how the console works

Comment: @11thdimension If you're talking about that `Array(0)` next to `__proto__`, that is the array's _prototype_. It should always have a length of zero.

Comment: @JLRishe That's what I was talking about, thanks.

Comment: Thank you all for the hints and explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the comments hinted at the issue here, but I don't see one that fully and correctly explains it. Here is what happened.

The initial one-line display of the array is created at the time you call `console.log()`. Simply *viewing* the log doesn't change anything (contrary to what one or two comments say). And subsequent updates to the array don't change this one-line view either.

But when you click the little triangle to *expand* the log entry, the expanded multiline display is created using the *current* array contents *at the time you click the triangle*. That is what causes the difference between the two. Your array was empty when you called `console.log()`, and you added an element to it after that but before you clicked to expand the display in the console.

If you want to get a full view of the array as it exists at the moment of the `console.log()` call, a good way to do it is to use `JSON.stringify()`. You can use the third argument to this function to pretty-print the result. So in your example, you might use:

```
console.log( JSON.stringify( lists, null, 4 ) );
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, so in this case `debugger` is a better choice?

Answer (score -1):

Check this out: `foo = []` create a new array and assigns a reference to it to a variable. Any other references are unaffected and still point to the original array.

`foo.length = 0` modifies the array itself. If you access it via a different variable, then you still get the modified array.
Lucky with that.