# Can not get value from Object(Key-value) in Javascript for IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I had create a Object to store key & value like

```
var labReportMap = new Object();
```

And put some value like

```
labReportMap ["1"] = "one";
```

And i am getting value back using statement like,
`labReportMap["one"]` , so it returns value one in all the internet explorer versions over 8.

It is displays `undefined` in version 8.

Comment: I don't why are you getting answer by `labReportMap["one"]` it should be `undefined` everywhere.

Comment: It works....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object-literal

Comment: '1' is the key 'one' is the value. you put the key in the square brackets and get the value.

Comment: But it does not works in IE8.

Comment: should be like labReportMap[1]

Comment: You might be confusing 'variables that contain keys' with 'strings that are keys'.