# JavaScript object referencing

Tags: javascript

So, I'm pretty new to JavaScript, and while I know the little tricks to do things like this in Java the same tricks don't really apply here, or at least I can't really figure out how to use them, so I'm currently using two objects in the form of collections:

```
var ConnectedClients_socket = {};
var ConnectedClients_networkId = {};
```

The hold a key/value pair to link a `networkID` to a client and then a duplicated object that uses the socket as a key. Any optimizations would be great, I'll be grabbing the client by the socket and ID a lot throughout the application.

**On to the problem:**

Upon disconnection I need to remove the client instance from the `ConnectedClients_networkId` object. From my understanding this is done using the `delete` keyword.

Here's the code I'm currently trying to use for this:

```
console.log('socket disconnected');
delete Client.ConnectedClients_networkId[Client.ConnectedClients_socket[socket].getNetworkId()];
delete Client.ConnectedClients_socket.socket;
```

However this is giving me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'getNetworkId' of undefined
```

which shows that

```
Client.ConnectedClients_socket[socket]
```

is returning undefined, while `Client.ConnectedClients_socket.socket` is being removed successfully a line later. I've looked up a few different pages on getting a value from a key in JavaScript, and I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the constructor for a client:

```
var Client = function(networkId, socket, ...) {
    this.networkId = networkId;
    this.socket = socket;
    ...
    ConnectedClients_socket.socket = this;
    ConnectedClients_networkId.networkId = this;
}
```

Comment: Nice job describing your problem; +1.

Comment: Indeed, very clean description. +1

Comment: Isnt the line Client.ConnectedClients_socket[socket].getNetworkId() should be 
Client.ConnectedClients_socket.socket.getNetworkId() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use dot notation there.

```
    delete Client.ConnectedClients_networkId[Client.ConnectedClients_socket.socket.getNetworkId()];
```

Bracket notation will parse it as JavaScript, so it's useful for dynamically getting a property.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I understand how this works. I've read in numerous areas that the bracket and dot notation were completely interchangeable. Could you please link me somewhere that this is explained in detail?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object-literal/1168814#1168814

Comment: @Christian.tucker Bracket notation accepts string only.

Comment: @Orion—bracket notation "accepts" any [*expression*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1), but as property names are strings the expression will be evaluated and then converted to a string using the internal *ToString* method.

Answer (score 2):

Quotes?

```
Client.ConnectedClients_socket['socket']
```

However, there is no need for this notation here.

```
Client.ConnectedClients_socket.socket
```

Is fine.

Bracket notation can be used for accessing members with special characters or by variable value.

```
Client.ConnectedClients_socket['someArr[]']
```

or

```
var x = 'socket';
Client.ConnectedClients_socket[x]
```