# TypeError: handlers.push is not a function

Tags: javascript

How to fix this issue?

```
// Add to the element's handler list, delegates in front
        if ( selector ) {
            handlers.splice( handlers.delegateCount++, 0, handleObj );
        } else {
            handlers.push( handleObj );
        }
```

Comment: is handlers an array?

Comment: Yes handlers is an array

Comment: I checked with this console.log( typeof handlers ); it return object,

Comment: in that case you need to follow this guidance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object-literal

Answer (score 2):

push() is an operation off of an array object such as:

```
var x = [];
var y = new Array();
x.push("me");
y.push("you");
```

To tell if a variable is an array you can do console.log(typeof [variable]); to see what type it is, or alternatively just console log the variable to see the contents.

If you are not using an array, but are using a javascript object, you should add elements to it via basic assignment.  Example:

```
var x = {}; //this works as an object
x.myNewVariable = "My new value";
```

After which you will be able to use and access that variable off of the object.  If you later want to remove that you can do so by:

```
delete x.myNewVariable;
```

Comment: how to check console's log sorry i am new 1

Comment: right click on the page and chose to view elements or something of that nature should bring up the console in firefox or chrome.

Comment: or you could do alert() insead of console.log() if that is easier.

Comment: I checked with this console.log( typeof handlers );  it return object,

Comment: then that is your problem.  the variable you are using is not an array.  the push function you are trying to use is related to an array object.

Comment: to add to an object you need to use the following syntax ```object.key = "value"``` instead of ```push```

Comment: Please give me detail explain, I can't able to understant.

Comment: @Ambai Mani I posted a comment under your answer with a link where it explains in more detail. Basically an object has key:value pairs, so you need to say something like ```handlers.key = handleObj``` , but I am not sure what the key is. Your other option may be to make handlers an array instead, which you could do by saying ```var handlers = []``` although I would need to see more of your code as it is too hard to tell what is going on with what you pasted