# Adding extra values to JS Object

Tags: javascript, object

Ok I have an HTML list containing the data I need.
It looks like this

```
ul
    li[data-trainer]>trainee
    li[data-trainer]>trainee
    li[data-trainer]>trainee
```

I iterate it and want to make an object that looks like this

```
{
    "Trainer":{0:Trainee1},
    "Trainer2":{1:Trainee2,2:Trainee3,3:Trainee4}
}
```

I tried this and a bunch more

```
var Data = new Object();
var i = 0;
$(".blah-blah-ul li.active").each(function(){
    i++;
    var trainer = $(this).attr("data-trainer");
    var trainee = $(this).text();
    Data[trainer] = {};
    Data[trainer][i] = trainee;
})
console.log(Data);
```

`Data[trainer][i] = trainee` leaves me with only the last trainee in the list.

Data from console.log:

```
Object
    Trainer1: Object
        2: Trainee2
    Trainer3: Object
        4: Trainee6
```

I tried making an array and using push or making a string but that didn't work.

If someone could please recommend a proper solution, it would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the HTML

```
<ul class="blah-blah-ul">
    <li class="active" data-trainer="Trainer1">Trainee1</li>
    <li class="active" data-trainer="Trainer1">Trainee2</li>
    <li data-trainer="Trainer2">Trainee3</li>
    <li data-trainer="Trainer2">Trainee4</li>
    <li class="active" data-trainer="Trainer3">Trainee5</li>
    <li class="active" data-trainer="Trainer3">Trainee6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I find it hard to understand how you get that kind of object from that kind of html structure. Can you please paste the real HTML or explain the situation you are in and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @IliyaReyzis - `.text` would be the contents between the greater and less than signs.  `...>here<...`, while `data-trainer` is a custom attribute inside the tag like `src` or `alt`.

Comment: @SanuelJackson Yeah, hats pretty abusive. I'm just trying to get the REAL html structure and the desired result.

Comment: I added the HTML above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem was in order to have more than one value assigned to the element in the array, the sub element must be an array.  This allows for adding multiple `Trainee` to the `Trainer` item in the `Data` object.

```js
var Data = new Object();
var i = 0;
$(".blah-blah-ul li.active").each(function(){
    i++;
    var trainer = $(this).attr("data-trainer");
    var trainee = $(this).text();
    if(typeof Data[trainer] === 'undefined') {
       Data[trainer] = {}; 
    }
  
    Data[trainer][i] = {trainee};
})
console.log(Data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="blah-blah-ul">
    <li class="active" data-trainer="Trainer1">Trainee1</li>
    <li class="active" data-trainer="Trainer1">Trainee2</li>
    <li data-trainer="Trainer2">Trainee3</li>
    <li data-trainer="Trainer2">Trainee4</li>
    <li class="active" data-trainer="Trainer3">Trainee5</li>
    <li class="active" data-trainer="Trainer3">Trainee6</li>
</ul>
```

Documentation on Javascript Arrays using Push, can be found here [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)

Comment: just realized i was declaring the opening array as `Object()` when it should have been `{}`

Comment: The data-trainer attribute is the same for some li's because they're coming from the same trainer.

Comment: Gotcha.  Let me revise.

Comment: Finished, the result is an array of Trainee's under each Trainer.

Comment: Argh, finally! You're a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach:

```
Data[trainer][i] = trainee;
```

and you can find more info here:
[How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object-literal)

Comment: `Data.trainer.i` would not work because it needs to be dynamic to `i` and to `trainer`. It would literally look for them as keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Data = {};
var i = 0;
$(".blah-blah-ul li.active").each(function(){
    i++;
    var trainer = $(this).attr("data-trainer");
    var trainee = $(this).text();
    Data[trainer] = {};
    Data[trainer][i] = trainee;
})
console.log(Data);
```

Comment: it still leaves me with the last trainee only :(

Comment: Almost, the problem you are having is every loop, you are re-initializing the array for Data[trainer], which effectively clears any prior data which may have been stored.