# Push object into and object Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a variable defined like this :

```
Var France ={

'Nice': {

    inputs: _.extend({
        attrs: {
            text : inp({
                text: { group: 'data', index: 1 },
                'font-size': { group: 'text', index: 2 },
                'font-family': { group: 'text', index: 3 },
                'font-weight': { group: 'text', index: 4 },

            }),
            image: inp({
                'xlink:href': { group: 'presentation', index: 1 }
            })
        },

    }),
    groups: cities

}};

var Paris =  {

    inputs: _.extend({
        attrs: {
            text : inp({
                text: { group: 'data', index: 1 },
                'font-size': { group: 'text', index: 2 },
                'font-family': { group: 'text', index: 3 },
                'font-weight': { group: 'text', index: 4 },

            }),
            image: inp({
                'xlink:href': { group: 'presentation', index: 1 }
            })
        },

    }),
    groups: cities

};
```

How can i push another city in France dynamically, like $(France).push(Paris) itried this but it dosent work, how can i make this work ?

Comment: Also a duplicate of [How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1168807/218196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as simple as:

`France['Paris'] = { ... }`

or

`France.Paris = { ... }`

You can use the `push` operation only on arrays (or other types which support this, but it's more advanced). You cannot push to objects, because they are not ordered.

An array is ordered, therefore you can use:

- `push` to add an element to the **end**
- `pop` to remove the element from the end and return it
- `unshift` to add an element to the **beginning**
- `shift` to remove the element from the beginning and return it.

The usage:

```
var x = [];
x.push(1);
//x is now [1];
x.unshift(2);
//x is now [2,1];
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation it's more clear for me now i knew i was doing something wrong. I ll accept your answer when in a few minutes when the site let me do it

Answer (score 1):

`Object` is not an `Array`. 
To create a new `field` you have to do something like

```
Paris["newkey"] = "aValue"; //Any value like {}, "", [], 0
```