# Is there a way to sort two parallel arrays like i am trying to

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am currently working on a program to sort a parallel set of arrays. The program is suppose to sort the first array with the `myArray.sort()` method/function. the second arrays values should stay in line with the first arrays sort when the program prints both of them out. I think i am very close to solving it but cant quite wrap my head around it.The `sortArrays()` function is the only logic that needs work the rest works perfectly. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Javascript

```
var employeeName = [];
var employeeSal = [];
var tmpArrayName = [];
var tmpArraySal = [];
var arraySize = 0;

function getInfo() {
    arraySize = parseInt(prompt("How many employee records will you be adding today?"));
    while (isNaN(arraySize)) {
        arraySize = parseInt(prompt("Error: please enter a valid positive number for question (How many employee records will you be adding today?)"));
    }
    for (var l = 0; l < arraySize; l++) {
        employeeName[l] = prompt("Please enter the employee's last name and first name (ex: Wayne John)");
        employeeSal[l] = parseInt(prompt("Please enter the employee's yearly salary (ex: 62000)"));
        while (isNaN(employeeSal[l])) {
            employeeSal[l] = parseInt(prompt("Please enter the employee's yearly salary (ex: 62000)"));
        }
    }
    tmpArrayName = employeeName;
    tmpArraySal = employeeSal;
    employeeName.sort();
    sortArrays();
    printResult();
}

function sortArrays() {
    var index = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < employeeName.length; i++) {
        index = employeeName.indexOf(tmpArrayName[i]);
        employeeSal[index] = tmpArraySal[i];
    }
}

function printResult() {
    for (var k = 0; k < employeeName.length; k++) {
        document.write('' + employeeName[k] + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + employeeSal[k] + '<br/>');
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<body onload="getInfo()">
    <div id ="content">

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Woah, copy and paste malfunction going on.

Comment: Your code is unreadable, and we should not have to do the cleanup job.

Comment: You couple the employees name with the salary right? So why do you use 2 arrays? You could instead use an object with key/value therefore you only have to sort once. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object-literal

Comment: I have to use the functionality we have learned and that's parallel arrays, sort(), indexOf(),and a few more basic ones. the objective was to use two arrays in parallel. It was my idea to sort just employeeName[] and change arrays employeeSal index's to match using a function. it looks solid but i am missing something. copying the arrays into temp arrays while i made the switches of the indexes seemed like the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that you were not making a copy of your arrays, but referencing the original ones. To make a copy, use slice:

```
tmpArrayName = employeeName;
tmpArraySal = employeeSal;
```

should be

```
tmpArrayName = employeeName.slice(0);
tmpArraySal = employeeSal.slice(0);
```

Comment: i haven't used slice before i am still learning. i added some print statements through out the code to do error checking and it seemed like i had the old arrays stored in the tmp arrays. i am still very green with the programming. I can not use the functions/object types you guys are mentioning tho we haven't learned those yet. I pretty much have to write the function to sort them instead of using one we haven't been introduced to yet. any ideas not using slice?

Comment: You're solution was perfect. This did fix the problem but i can not use it. Figured i would at least let people know that yours did work.

Comment: if it works, please check my solution off and upvote so it gets a green checkmark. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the final solution. @caleb-an your solution works great but i solved it by instead using a for loop to set the tmpArrays values to the original arrays.

```
//this code works fine but can not use
        //tmpArrayName = employeeName.slice(0);
        //tmpArraySal = employeeSal.slice(0);

       //this code does the same exact thing and works
       for (var e = 0; e < employeeName.length; e++)
       {
           tmpArrayName[e] = employeeName[e];
           tmpArraySal[e] = employeeSal[e];
       }
```