# javascript add multiple properties to an object at same time

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
var x = {
  'a' : 1,
  'b' : 2
}
```

Then, I want to add the following to the object (my pseudocode):

```
x += {
  'c' : 3,
  'd' : 4
}
```

This obviously doesn't work as expected.. I basically end up with a "[Object][Object]" string.  But what I really want is this:

```
var x = {
  'a' : 1,
  'b' : 2,
  'c' : 3,
  'd' : 4
}
```

I feel like there should be some sort of built-in operator or easy way to do this, other than just individually adding the properties or using a loop.  But maybe I am wrong.  Thoughts?

Comment: For the dupe: you'll want the second answer

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object-literal

Comment: FYI I found this [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) which is exactly what I'm looking for, but it's for arrays not objects. I can't see that there is an object equivalent.  Also it's EM6.  But just putting more clarity into what I was looking for.  I guess the long story short is it's simply not doable at this time. Thanks for links!

Comment: Actually I just found the [assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method which is what I was hoping/looking for, though it too is EM6.  Which in retrospect was in one of the answers on the link @Cerbrus posted. doh.

Answer (score 0):

```
// in React Js

let object1 = {
            prop1 : "a",
            prop2 : "b",
            prop3 : "c",
        };
        let object2 = {
            prop4 : "d",
            prop5 : "e",
            prop6 : "f",
        };
        let newObj = { ...object1, ...object2 };
```

Comment: Yes I know I can do this. I was looking for a way to *not* have to do this.

Comment: It's not at the same time I think