# Object key becomes string "key"

Tags: javascript, object

How do I write this?

```
chatBox_array.push({key:val_d65f});
```

They 'key', somehow gets to just "key":value, for objects instead of the value inside the key. It becomes sometime like the following.

```
0: Object
key: "false"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
key: "blue"
__proto__: Object
```

Here's the full code.

```
var chatBox_vars = [{'return_url':chatBox_return_url},{'base_color':chatBox_base_color}, 
{'mid_color':chatBox_mid_color}, 
{'init_open':chatBox_init_open},
{'init_open':chatBox_mx_logo}, 
{'welcome_msg':chatBox_welcome_msg},    
{'clientid':chatBox_clientid}];

    var chatBox_array = [];

    for (var i=chatBox_vars.length;i--;){
            var item_6dds3=chatBox_vars[i];

            for (var key in item_6dds3) {
                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(item_6dds3, key)) {
                var val_d65f = item_6dds3[key];
                    if (val_d65f == null || val_d65f == 'undefined' || val_d65f == ''){} else {
                        console.log(key);
                        chatBox_array.push({key:val_d65f}); 
                    }   
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating an object before setting property

```
var obj = {}; obj[key] = val_d65f;
chatBox_array.push(obj);
```

Comment: Substituted using bracket notation to set property using reference to variable `key` for setting "key" as property for each object literal created . See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object/