# Add dynamic key-values to JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to create a json object in javascript containing dynamic values. I need to pass this JSON Object to server through an AJAX call. But I'm unable to add the dynamic values.

```
var finalJSONObj={};
for loop(int i = 0; i<10;i++){
    // gets the values of rows i need to add .. 
    var taskValue = tasks[i]; // need to add this in the JSON Object
}
```

My final JSON object should look like:

```
finalJSONObj = {
    tasks1: 'taskValue',
    tasks2: 'taskValue',
    tasks3: 'taskValue',
    tasks4: 'taskValue',
    userId: 'abcd',
    date: '23/09/2016'
};
```

Need to add the "taskValue" retrieved from the for loop for each task in the JSON Object. Any Thoughts?

Comment: Do you know how to add `key`/`value` pair to a Javascript Object? Please refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1168814/427146)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.
In forloop just change this syntax

```
var finalJSONObj={};
  for loop(int i = 0; i<10;i++){
  // gets the values of rows i need to add .. 
  finalJSONObj['task'+ (i + 1)] = tasks[i]; // need to add this in the JSON Object
}
```

Here key will be task + i which will be task1, task2 etc and value will be mapped to this key from your tasks array.

Comment: This works fine! :) I finally got the results iterating through the request.getParameterValues() in my servlet. Thanks a ton! :)

Comment: Always happy to help :) yw

Comment: This is not going to work, since `'task' + i + `1 will evaluate to `task01`, `task11`, etc. (It is grouped as `('task' + i) + 1`).

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var finalJSONObj={};
for (var i = 0; i<tasks.length; i++) {
    finalJSONObj[('tasks' + (i+1))] = tasks[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great! :)