# React-Native - Object.assign children change

Tags: javascript, object, react-native, assign

sry if this question is still there but i searched for it and i didn´t find a solution. Also i couldn´t get any hint out of the [Developer.Mozilla](http://www.developer.mozilla.org) website where Objects.assign etc. is described well.

> **The question:**
>
> How can i change the children of an object? With exactly the output  i described in the following.

**Sample-Code**

```
var obj= {test: [{a: 2}, {b: 3}]};
var newChildren = [{a: 3}, {b: 5}, {c: 1}];

//I read the obj key value by the following:
var objKey = Object.entries(obj)[0][0]

//Here i want to have some code to get the following result
//My momentary regarding to @webdeb

var output = Object.assign({}, {objKey: newChildren})

actual output: // {objKey: [{a: 3}, {b: 5}, {c: 1}]}

wanted output: // {test: [{a: 3}, {b: 5}, {c: 1}]}
```

*I have no other option to get the code in some other format so the "input" is needed in the way i described. And i need to set the `objKey` as a variable, because i have multiple keys in my code wich i have to set for multiple children. (Doing some filter stuff)*

Thanks for your help

BR
Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following solution gave me the exact result i wanted:

```
obj[objKey] = newChildren;

console.log(obj) // {test: [{a: 3}, {b: 5}, {c: 1}]}
```

I took this solution regarding to the question:

[How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object)

**The importance for me was to have the `object-key` as a variable. The described solution gives me the option to add a value to`more` than just one `static` key.**

Comment: Thanks anyway for your informations :) I didn´t spell the question 100% pefect maybe :) I will mark this answer as solution.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use `Object` as variable Name..

Ok, lets say the Object is now `obj`

Without modification of the `obj`

`var newObj = Object.assign({}, obj, {test: newChildren})`

Or just, (modifies the `obj`)

`obj.test = newChildren`

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Hey webdeb. Thanks for your fast response. It works almost as i wanted. Just the "test" has to be variable. I UPDATED the question for further and detailed information. And ofc I edited the var Object :)