# How to add object into object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am aware there is push() to add oject into array. But how to add object into object.

```
var osubcategories = {};

for (var i=0; i<data.length; ++i){
      var tempkey = data[i].scid;   // here tempkey will be any number sat 15 20 30 etc

      // how to add this tempkey along with true in osubcategories
 }
```

I want output like this for each tempkey in loop:

```
osubcategories = {"15" : true, "23": true, "55" : true}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object)

Comment: `osubcategories[tempkey] = true;` in loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `osubcategories[tempkey] = true;`

EDIT: forgot tempkey

Comment: I am not sure I get your comment.

Comment: The tempkey should be a temporary key. In cases, you want to keep the keys unique when used in functions/code. Decent answer though. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var osubcategories = {};
for (var i=0; i<data.length; ++i){
  var tempkey = data[i].scid;   // here tempkey will be any number sat 15 20    30 etc
  // the following line will add the properties to the "osubcategories" object
  osubcategories[tempKey] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this..

```js
var osubcategories = {};
var data = [15,20,30];
var tempkey = {};
for (var i=0; i<data.length; ++i){
      osubcategories[data[i]] = true;
}
console.log(osubcategories);
```