# How to add new property to object?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have an object

```
 let data = {
                    "data 1": {
                        "row1": "aaaa",

                    },
                    "data 2": {
                        "row3": "nnnnn",

                    }
                }
```

And I want to add some properties with dynamic names and vals to get such an object:

```
  let data = {
                    "data 1": {
                        "row1": "aaaa",
                        "row2": "bbbb",
                    },
                    "data 2": {
                        "row3": "nnnnn",
                        "row4": "sssss",
                        "row11": "bbb",
                        "eeee": "ffff"
                    },
                    "dynamic1": {
                        "dyn_2": "dyn_val_1",
                        "dyn_3": "dyn_val_2"
                    }
                }
```

I have tried this code, but it overwrites the data obj with the last value instead of adding

```
      responseJson.results.forEach(function (value) {

                data[value.date] = { [value.event_id] : [value.name] };

            })
```

Comment: please add `responseJson` as well.

Comment: Is responseJson.results your data ? or an array ?

Comment: @FelixKling no, I want to add new object "dynamic1": {
                        "dyn_2": "dyn_val_1",
                        "dyn_3": "dyn_val_2"
                    } in data object

Comment: @SERG: Sure. But when you are saying that you are *overwriting* the value. So that's exactly what you should not be doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, then don't overwrite the property. Add to the object instead:

```
responseJson.results.forEach(function (value) {
  if (!data[value.date) {
    data[value.date] = {};
  }
  data[value.date][value.event_id] = value.name;
});
```

Related: [How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1168807/218196)

Comment: Thanks. That's what I need.