# How to add value of second object to first object?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript on my own and am going through tutorials and cannot understand how to add the value of the second object to the first object. I tried to look at this [How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object) but I couldn't follow it.
Below is the code I wrote:

```
 var person1 = {
      name: 'Joe',
  role: 'specialist'
};
var person2 = {
  name: 'Mr. Roberts',
  role: 'supervisor'
};

function addObjectProperty(obj1, key, obj2) {
  addObjectProperty(person1, 'manager', person2);

  return (person1.manager = (person2.name + person2.role));
}

console.log(person1.manager);
```

My result returns:

```
undefined
```

But it should return:

```
//  --> { name: 'Mr. Roberts', role: 'supervisor' }
```

Could someone kindly advise me further? Thank you! :)

Comment: The call to `addObjectProperty()` needs to be **outside** the function, not inside.

Comment: @Pointy When I do your suggestion I get: **Mr. Roberts, supervisor** and not **{ name: 'Mr. Roberts', role: 'supervisor' }** . How would I fix this? I tried adding **obj1[key] = obj2** but it didn't change anything. Or would the way Ibrahim wrote the code below be the best way to go? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var person1 = {
  name: 'Joe',
  role: 'specialist'
};
var person2 = {
  name: 'Mr. Roberts',
  role: 'supervisor'
};

function addObjectProperty(obj1, key, obj2) {
  obj1[key] = obj2; // using bracket notaion to add obj2 as a property of obj1 under the key key
}

// call the function outside its definition or it'll cause an infinite recursion
addObjectProperty(person1, 'manager', person2); // person1.manager = person2

console.log(person1);
```