# How to append to an object with Google Apps Script Editor

Tags: object, google-apps-script, google-api, append, google-apps-script-editor

This is in Google Script Editor. I've done a lot of searching but for some reason I can't find any information about a simple thing such as appending to an object.

I have an object like this:

```
var get_options = {
    'method': 'get',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
};
```

How would I go about appending to that object?

I want to add `'authorization': 'token',` to that object so the object will look like this:

```
var get_options = {
    'method': 'get',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'authorization': 'token',
};
```

Please help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: get_options[“authorization”] = “token” or get_options.authorization = “token”. This is a JavaScript-related question.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize google app script editor utilizes javascript syntax like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google App Script (GAS) uses javascript platform. So whenever you have some basic coding syntax you want to look up, refer to [javascript documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970435.aspx)

To answer your question in brief,to add key pair value to get_options you would do the following

```
var get_options = {
    'method': 'get',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
};
 get_options.authorization = “token”
//or
get_options["authorization"] = “token”
```

More detailed explanation you can be found in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that it is using the JS platform. I thought parts of it were just similar.. not identical. Thanks again!