# How to associate array value to references

Tags: javascript, associative-array

i have 2 arrays. One with users and other with user's manager

```
var user=[a,b,c,d,e];
var manager=[x,y,z]
```

how to associate users to respective managers if the manager is same for users

```
manager  user
x        a,b
y         c
z        d,e
```

i'm looking to achieve in javascipt.

Comment: So you *have* a mapping in-hand, and you want to know the best way to represent that mapping in JavaScript?

Comment: do u mean like manager_user = [{"mgr": "x", "users": ["a", "b", "e"]}];

Comment: It would probably be easier if you described how you wanted to use this thing.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy you can do it by

```
var manager_user = [
    {
        "mgr": "x",
        "users": [
            "a",
            "b",
            "e"
        ]
    }
];
```

And it's a validated json!

**Update:**
Based on yr comment you can use functions and do object literals:

```
var Manager_User = function(mgr, usrs) {

    return {
        manager: mgr,
        usrs: usrs,
        addUser: function(mgr, usr) {
            usrs.push(usr);
        },
        removeUser: function(index) {
            usrs.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
}

var mgrUser = new Manager_User("x", ["a", "b", "c"]);
```

I've uploaded some of my js examples on [github](https://github.com/bahmani00/JsCalculator), you can have a look, especially calc.js

Comment: Be careful with downvotes, we are not sure if this is what OP really wants.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown don't understand what u mean but it's a validated json

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code tho, but your answer may be wrong, if OP update with a new information that will invalidate it.

Comment: how can i construct this?

Comment: @DanielB What do you mean by "*it's a validated json*"? I don't see any JSON in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can keep key value pair. key as manager.value as a array of {a,b}.

```
var obj = {
key1: value1,
key2: value2
};

obj["key3"] = "value3";

obj["x"] = {"a","b"};
```

[How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object)