# Remove nested child from redux state following Firebase 'child_removed' listener triggered

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-redux-firebase

My redux state looks like this (its synced with Firebase).

```
{
  profile: {
    activeUsers: {
      Iiva2BGZffNTH84glOLXv8QHVTF2: {
        sex: male,
        age: 20,
      },
      PkfMxrN09RN7ygoBMWqm4jheEOx1: {
        sex: female,
        age: 20,
      },
      zQiGXvcUGmRSKUdr719621QleUw2: {
        sex: male,
        age: 25,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to remove user zQiGXvcUGmRSKUdr719621QleUw2

Heres my action creator

```
  Firebase.database()
    .ref('profiles/activeUsers')
    .on(
      'child_removed',
      (snapshot) => {
        dispatch(_activeUserChildRemoved(snapshot));
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err.toString());
        Alert.alert(err);
      },
    );
};

const _activeUserChildRemoved = snapshot => ({
  type: ACTIVE_USER_CHILD_REMOVED,
  payload: snapshot,
});
```

and finally here is my reducer

```
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIVE_USER_CHILD_REMOVED:
      const key4Del = action.payload.key;
      return { //what goes here??? };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

What do i return from reducer in order to remove the user referenced by snapshot.key from redux?
Help is much appreciated

Comment: maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!!

```
case ACTIVE_USER_CHILD_REMOVED:
      const key4Del = action.payload.key;
      const oldState = state;
      delete oldState.activeUsers[key4Del];
      return { ...oldState };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the user by not **mutating** the state and simply by using **destructuring**.

Right now you're mutating the `state` directly by deleting object property from `oldState`

```
case ACTIVE_USER_CHILD_REMOVED:
  const key4Del = action.payload.key;
  const { [key4Del]: _, ...activeUsers} = state.activeUsers
  return {...state, activeUsers }
```

Spread Syntax will shallow compare the object, therefore you need to merge the filtered object again to generate a new state.