# Javascript: Add key/value pairs in nested dict; key and value are variables

Tags: javascript, dictionary, object, nested, keyvaluepair

I have a dictionary of the following structure:

```
myDict = {key1:{innerKey1:innerValue1, innerKey2:innerValue2}, key2:{},...}
```

Based on:
[How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object)

I tried to add inner key/value pairs like this:

```
someArray=['foo','bar']
var identifier = someArray[0]
var info = someArray[1]
myDict[key1][identifier] = info;
```

Or like this:

```
myDict[key1].identifier = info;
```

But I get the error **'cannot set property of undefined'**. I think this is due to the identifier not being defined in myDict yet, but I cannot figure out how to achieve this:

```
myDict = {key1:{innerkey1:innerValue1, innerKey2: innerValue2, foo:bar,...}, key2:{},...}
```

Please note: I know in this example the assignment of variables is not necessary. I need to figure out the concept for a bigger, more complex project and this is the minimum "non-working" example.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your snippet, `key1` doesn't seem to be defined.

You also want to make sure that the object is defined before trying to access it

```
someArray=['foo','bar']
var identifier = someArray[0]
var info = someArray[1]
if (!myDict[key1]) myDict[key1] = {};
myDict[key1][identifier] = info;
```

Answer (score 3):

Bracket notation requires the key be a string:

```
myDict["key1"][identifier] = info;
```

Or just use dot notation:

```
myDict.key1[identifier] = info;
```

Comment: This would have been my answer too, not sure why someone thought it was bad.

Comment: key1 is probably a variable to be fair.

Comment: I know @Morphyish, but the fact that they have not defined it has caused the error.

Comment: Since identifier is a variable defined above `myDict.key1[identifier] = info` would be the correct solution

Comment: Fixed @BJRINT, any better?

Comment: @JackBashford my own bet is on the fact that `key1` has no associated value in the dict when they are trying to update its property ;D