# How can I set a value to an key value pair property in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Let's say that I have the given object:

```
export interface File {
  id: string;
  displayname: string;
  filesize: number;
  isarchived: boolean;
  userId: string;
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

and the following method:

```
export class BasketService {
    addFile(file: File ) { //Some code here }
}
```

Than I call my method like this:

```
this._basketService.addFile({
  id: file.id,
  displayname: file.originalEntry['displayname'],
  filesize: file.originalEntry['filesize'],
  isarchived: file.originalEntry['isarchived'],
  userId: this._appSession.user.id,
  ???: file.originalEntry // <=== How can I set the key value pair here?
});
```

The object:

`file.originalEntry is [key: string]`. I would like to pass the entire object 
   instead of individual key/ value pairs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it putting explicitly the key/ value pairs that I needed in my object like this:

```
const digitalObject = {
        id: file.id,
        displayname: file.originalEntry['displayname'],
        filesize: file.originalEntry['filesize'],
        isarchived: file.originalEntry['isarchived'],
        userId: this._appSession.user.id,
        code: file.originalEntry['code'],
        needle: file.originalEntry['needle'],
        x8: file.originalEntry['x8'][0],
        x5: file.originalEntry['x5'][0],
        8: file.originalEntry['8'][0],
        5: file.originalEntry['5'][0],
        creationtime: file.creationTime
    };

    this._basketService.addFile(digitalObject);
```

Thanks for the all contributions.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
this._basketService.addFile({
  id: file.id,
  displayname: file.originalEntry['displayname'],
  filesize: file.originalEntry['filesize'],
  isarchived: file.originalEntry['isarchived'],
  userId: this._appSession.user.id,
  keyValue: {key:file.id, value: file.originalEntry}
});
```

Comment: keyValue is not a property of my object. `export interface File { [key: string]: any }` since the property has no name how can I set a value to it?

Answer (score 1):

if the declaration is like this:

```
public dictionary: { [key: string]: string } = {};
```

you can set its value in this way:

```
this.dictionary = { ID: key, Value: defaultValue }; // key and defaultValue are variables
```

in your case pass this:

```
{ ID: key, Value: defaultValue }
```