# How can I add a new key:value pair to an existing Javascript object dynamically within a loop

Tags: javascript

I would like to calculate a new value based on two objects and add the result as new object to the existing array.

**The input looks like:**

```
[{
    "trades": [
        {
        "fields": {
                "orderOpenPrice": "1.40000",
                "orderTakeProfit": "1.50000",
                [...]

        },
        },

        {
          "fields": {
                "orderOpenPrice": "1.30000",
                "orderTargetPrice": "1.50000",
                [...]
        }
        },
        {
        "fields": {
                "orderOpenPrice": "1.50000",
                "orderTargetPrice": "1.55000",
                [...]
        }
        },

        [...]

}]
```

**This is the desired output:**

```
[{
    "trades": [
        {
        "fields": {
                "orderOpenPrice": "1.40000",
                "orderTakeProfit": "1.50000",
                "pipsTargetedKey": "10000",
                [...]

        },
        },

        {
          "fields": {
                "orderOpenPrice": "1.30000",
                "orderTakeProfit": "1.50000",
                "pipsTargetedKey": "20000",
                [...]
        }
        },
        {
        "fields": {
                "orderOpenPrice": "1.50000",
                "orderTakeProfit": "1.55000",
                "pipsTargetedKey": "5000",
                [...]
        }
        },

        [...]

}]
```

I tried two different approaches using this thread: [How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object):

**Using `assign`:**

```
[...]
for (var i = 0; i < tradesTotal; i++) {
    pipsTargeted = Math.abs(trades[i].fields.orderOpenPrice - trades[i].fields.orderTakeProfit);
    trades[i].fields.assign(trades[i].fields, {pipsTargetedKey: pipsTargeted});
}
[...]
```

**Using `dot notation`:**

```
[...]
for (var i = 0; i < tradesTotal; i++) {
    pipsTargeted = Math.abs(trades[i].fields.orderOpenPrice - trades[i].fields.orderTakeProfit);
    trades[i].fields.pipsTargetedKey = pipsTargeted
}
[...]
```

However, both attempts do not add another key:value pair.

**Edit on request:**

```
tradesTotal = Object.keys(trades).length;

// manipulate trades object
for (var i = 0; i < tradesTotal; i++) {

    // format dateTime
    trades[i].fields.orderOpenTime = (trades[i].fields.orderOpenTime).replace('T', ' ');
    if (trades[i].fields.orderCloseTime !== null)
    trades[i].fields.orderCloseTime = (trades[i].fields.orderCloseTime).replace('T', ' ');

    // format orderType
    if (trades[i].fields.orderType === 0) {
        trades[i].fields.orderType = 'Buy'
    } else if (trades[i].fields.orderType === 1) {
        trades[i].fields.orderType = 'Sell'
    } else if (trades[i].fields.orderType === 2) {
        trades[i].fields.orderType = 'Buy Limit'
    } else if (trades[i].fields.orderType === 3) {
        trades[i].fields.orderType = 'Sell Limit'
    } else if (trades[i].fields.orderType === 4) {
        trades[i].fields.orderType = 'Buy Stop'
    } else if (trades[i].fields.orderType === 5) {
        trades[i].fields.orderType = 'Sell Stop'
    } else if (trades[i].fields.orderType === 6) {
        trades[i].fields.orderType = 'Bank Transaction'
    }

    // calculate R:R and TP + SL in pips and add result to object
    if (stopLoss && takeProfit > 0) {
        pipsRisked = Math.abs(trades[i].fields.orderOpenPrice - trades[i].fields.orderStopLoss);
        pipsTargeted = Math.abs(trades[i].fields.orderOpenPrice - trades[i].fields.orderTakeProfit);
        rrRatio = (pipsTargeted / pipsRisked);
        trades[i].fields.pipsRiskedKey = pipsRisked;
        trades[i].fields.pipsTargetedKey = pipsTargeted;
        trades[i].fields.pipsRRKey = rrRatio;
    }
}
```

Comment: if that's your inner loop you'll need to add `.length` to  `tradesTotal`

Comment: @NickParsons tradesTotal is a variable assigned with the object.length already, this is just fine.

Comment: can you add your outer loop?

Comment: @NickParsons added the original code, thanks.

Comment: Is the `trades` variable the property trades inside your array of objects? Or is it your entire array input?

Comment: @NickParsons it is the entire array input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned `trades` is an array. When you do `Object.keys()` on an array, you get the indexes of that array. This can be simplified to just `trades.length` as they are the same thing.

Currently, you're looping over `trades`, which allow you to access each object in your array. Each object has a `trades` property with an array, which you also need to loop over. This means you need a nested loop. One to loop over all your objects in your larger, and another to loop over all your objects in your `trades` property array. This can be done like so:

```js
const tradesTotal = [{
  "trades": [{
      "fields": {
        "orderOpenPrice": "1.40000",
        "orderTakeProfit": "1.50000",


      },
    },

    {
      "fields": {
        "orderOpenPrice": "1.30000",
        "orderTargetPrice": "1.50000",

      }
    },
    {
      "fields": {
        "orderOpenPrice": "1.50000",
        "orderTargetPrice": "1.55000",

      }
    },
  ]
}];


for (var i = 0; i < tradesTotal.length; i++) {
  var trades = tradesTotal[i].trades;
  for (var j = 0; j < trades.length; j++) {
    var pipsTargeted = Math.abs(trades[j].fields.orderOpenPrice - trades[j].fields.orderTakeProfit);
    trades[j].fields.pipsTargetedKey = pipsTargeted
  }

}
console.log(tradesTotal);
```

Comment: @Phanti no worries. Currently the equation you're using to calculate `pipsTargetedKey` is incorrect so it won't give you you're desired result exactly. (some of your objects use `orderTakeProfit` and some use `orderTargetPrice`)

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function and [spead operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const trades = [
  {
    "fields": {
      "orderOpenPrice": "1.40000",
      "orderTakeProfit": "1.50000",
    },
  },
  {
    "fields": {
      "orderOpenPrice": "1.30000",
      "orderTakeProfit": "1.50000",
    }
  },
  {
    "fields": {
      "orderOpenPrice": "1.50000",
      "orderTakeProfit": "1.55000",
    }
  }
]

const mappedTrades = trades.map(trade => {
  const {orderOpenPrice, orderTakeProfit} = trade.fields
  return {
     ...trade,
     fields: {
        ...trade.fields,
        pipsTargetedKey: Math.abs(Number(orderOpenPrice) - Number(orderTakeProfit))
     }
  }
})
```

Another way is to use something like [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) or [Object.observe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe).