# How to add key value pair to object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a Datasource which contains a nested array of objects.
I have been able to select key value pair, and now I want to add those values to the top level of the object, i.e outside the nested object.

Initial array:

```
 data= [
  {
    "flowId": 7079,
    "flowName": "jackson-demo",
    "version": 1,
    "CreatedDate": "2020-04-02",
    "UpdateDate": "",
    "LastRunDate": "2020-04-02",
    "active": false,

"properties": [
  {
    "id": 7080,
    "key": "country",
    "value": "in",
    "category": "General"
  },
  {
    "id": 7081,
    "key": "source",
    "value": "hive",
    "category": "General"
  }
  ]

  },
  {

"flowId": 7079,
"flowName": "jackson-demo",
"version": 1,
"CreatedDate": "2020-04-02",
"UpdateDate": "",
"LastRunDate": "2020-04-02",
"active": false,

"properties": [
  {
    "id": 7080,
    "key": "country",
    "value": "au",
    "category": "General"
  },
  {
    "id": 7081,
    "key": "source",
    "value": "aws",
    "category": "General"
  }
  ]

} ]
```

Using the below code I am able to get the key value pair:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  data[i].properties.forEach((arrayItem, i) => {
    if (arrayItem.key === 'country') {
      console.log('Key: ' + arrayItem.key + ' ' + 'Value: ' + arrayItem.value);
    }
  });
}
```

Output of Code:

```
Key: country Value: au 
Key: country Value: in
```

How do I push these values back in the array so that my new array looks like this:

```
data= [
  {
    "flowId": 7079,
    "flowName": "jackson-demo",
    "version": 1,
    "CreatedDate": "2020-04-02",
    "UpdateDate": "",
    "LastRunDate": "2020-04-02",
    "active": false,
    "country": "in"

"properties": [
  {
    "id": 7080,
    "key": "country",
    "value": "in",
    "category": "General"
  },
  {
    "id": 7081,
    "key": "source",
    "value": "hive",
    "category": "General"
  }
  ]

  },
  {

"flowId": 7079,
"flowName": "jackson-demo",
"version": 1,
"CreatedDate": "2020-04-02",
"UpdateDate": "",
"LastRunDate": "2020-04-02",
"active": false,
"country":"au"

"properties": [
  {
    "id": 7080,
    "key": "country",
    "value": "au",
    "category": "General"
  },
  {
    "id": 7081,
    "key": "source",
    "value": "aws",
    "category": "General"
  }
  ]

} ]
```

Comment: [There is no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: You already keep track of the index of the object, inside your loop. Why not just use that index to push it back on the right level

Comment: Removed the `json` tag and "JSON" from question. Please read the description before adding that tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0):

Try update `data[i]` using spread operator :

```
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  data[i].properties.forEach((arrayItem, i) => {
    if (arrayItem.key === 'country') {
      data[i] = { ...data[i] , arrayItem }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.fromEntries`:

```
for (let item of data) {
  Object.assign(item,
    Object.fromEntries(item.properties.map(({key, value}) => [key, value]))
  );
}
```

In case you only want to add *some* of these pairs, you can chain a `.filter` to the `.map` result, or if you just need *one* ("country"), use a more basic programming pattern:

```
for (let item of data) {
  item.country = item.properties.find(({key}) => key == "country").value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This creates a new array with copies of your objects having an additional `country` property if it's found:

```js
const addCountry = data => data .map (({properties, ...rest}) => {
  const country = properties .find (({key}) => key == 'country')
  return {
    ... rest,
    ... (country ? {country: country .value} : {}),
    properties
  }
})


const data = [{flowId: 7079, flowName: "jackson-demo", version: 1, CreatedDate: "2020-04-02", UpdateDate: "", LastRunDate: "2020-04-02", active: false, properties: [{id: 7080, key: "country", value: "in", category: "General"}, {id: 7081, key: "source", value: "hive", category: "General"}]}, {flowId: 7079, flowName: "jackson-demo", version: 1, CreatedDate: "2020-04-02", UpdateDate: "", LastRunDate: "2020-04-02", active: false, properties: [{id: 7080, key: "country", value: "au", category: "General"}, {id: 7081, key: "source", value: "aws", category: "General"}]}];

console .log (
  addCountry (data)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

If the only use of `properties` in the output is already satisfied by this extraction, then you could skip the `properties` line in the output and have more lightweight versions for further processing.

We could, of course, choose to mutate the original data, but we're not barbarians, right?