# How to push data to array in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I am new in nodejs, and I don't know how to push data to multidimensional array in nodejs.

So I have

```
var fruits = {
    a: { x: 1, y: 2 },
    b: { x: 3, y: 4 }
};
```

How to add

```
c: { x: 5, y: 6 }
```

?

I try but not work.. Thanks :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object)

Comment: That is not an array. That is an object.

Answer (score 0):

That is not an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), it is an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).
If you want to add `c: { x: 5, y: 6 }` to it just use `fruits.c = { x: 5, y: 6 };`

```js
var fruits = {
    a: { x: 1, y: 2 },
    b: { x: 3, y: 4 }
};

fruits.c = { x: 5, y: 6 };

console.log(fruits);
```

More on the topic:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Hope it helped you :)

Comment: yeah, sorry :D Thank you very much! :)

Comment: It's ok, I am glad it helped you! By the way, if you need more help with JavaScript [this free course on JavaScript Algorithms and Data Structures](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn#javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures) could help you understand JS in a step by step way.