# JSON.stringify not adding commas between contained objects

Tags: javascript, json, loops, object, stringify

Although following the excellent information in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47116829/11308019 — especially the "Year 2018 answer" — I am trying to figure out a `JSON.stringify` problem. Example code follows...

```
const globAll = require('glob-all')
const fs = require('fs')
const cacheFile = '.base64imgs.json'

// clear cacheFile...
fs.writeFileSync(cacheFile,'')
let bCache = {}

files = globAll.sync([
  'src/images/*.jpg',
  'src/images/*.png',
])

files.forEach(file => {
  var bRes = `data for ${file} would go here`
  var bAdd = {file, bRes}
  bCache =  {...bCache, ...bAdd}
  fs.writeFileSync(cacheFile, JSON.stringify(bCache, null, 2), {flag: 'a'})
})
```

This results in output in `.base64imgs.json` like the following:

```
{
  "file": "src/images/1984-07-11_01_retouched_1280x720.jpg",
  "bRes": "data for src/images/1984-07-11_01_retouched_1280x720.jpg would go here"
}{
  "file": "src/images/2020-01-31--curmudgeonishish-2019_1280x726.jpg",
  "bRes": "data for src/images/2020-01-31--curmudgeonishish-2019_1280x726.jpg would go here"
}{
  "file": "src/images/alarm-clock-4711181_1280x853.jpg",
  "bRes": "data for src/images/alarm-clock-4711181_1280x853.jpg would go here"
}{
  "file": "src/images/almond-21502_1280x853.jpg",
  "bRes": "data for src/images/almond-21502_1280x853.jpg would go here"
}
```

...which obviously isn't valid JSON because there's no comma between the objects within the containing `bCache` object. (I also tried using arrays only, arrays within an object, objects within an array, etc.; same results each time.) I assume the fault is my own, but my days-long searches for answers in SO and other similar sources haven't shown me what I'm doing wrongly. So, any help and/or correction will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't `bCache` be an array rather than an object? so `let bCache = [];` and `bCache = [...bCache, bAdd];`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey did try all combos as noted in last paragraph. No joy. :-/

Comment: Besides the array instead of object, part of your problem is using `...bAdd` instead of just `bAdd` — Heretic Monkey shows it but doesn't mention it... you want to add the _object_, but with `...bAdd` you are first _expanding_ bAdd with the spread operator and adding _the expansion_ to bCache.

Comment: @HereticMonkey --- from what the others said below, looks as if I should've listened to you in the first place. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use an array instead of an object for bCache. And you should probably write out all at once instead of appending in a loop.

```js
let bCache = []
let files = ['file 1','file 2','file 3']

files.forEach(file => {
  var bRes = `data for ${file} would go here`
  var bAdd = {file, bRes}
  bCache = [...bCache, bAdd]
})
console.log(JSON.stringify(bCache, null, 2))
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like that'll do it. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't write the JSON inside the loop. Create an array of all the data, and write it once at the end of the loop.

```js
const globAll = require('glob-all')
const fs = require('fs')
const cacheFile = '.base64imgs.json'

files = globAll.sync([
  'src/images/*.jpg',
  'src/images/*.png',
])

bCache = files.map(file => {
  var bRes = `data for ${file} would go here`
  return {file, bRes}
});

fs.writeFileSync(cacheFile, JSON.stringify(bCache, null, 2));
```