# push into array of nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

My array is of multiple objects

```
[
  { key: 'javascript', count: 12 },
  { key: 'typescript', count: 15 },
  { key: 'angular', count: 13 }
]
```

How can I push inside each object to make it like

```
[
  { key: 'javascript', count: 12, selected: false },
  { key: 'typescript', count: 15, selected: false },
  { key: 'angular', count: 13, selected: false }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 2):

```js
let t = [
  { key: 'javascript', count: 12 },
  { key: 'typescript', count: 15 },
  { key: 'angular', count: 13 }
];

t.forEach(myObj => (myObj.selected = false));

console.log(t);
```

After author commented:

```js
let t = {
0:[ { key: 'javascript', count: 12 }, { key: 'typescript', count: 15 }, { key: 'angular', count: 13 } ], 
99:[ { key: 'javascript', count: 12 }, { key: 'typescript', count: 15 }, { key: 'angular', count: 13 } ], 
};

Object.keys(t).forEach(myNum => 
t[myNum].forEach(myObj => myObj.selected = false));

console.log(t);
```

Comment: @baymax  I figure out, I made some mistakes while asking question, 
my array is like, [0:[
  { key: 'javascript', count: 12 },
  { key: 'typescript', count: 15 },
  { key: 'angular', count: 13 }
]
];

Comment: ```let t = {
0:[ { key: 'javascript', count: 12 }, { key: 'typescript', count: 15 }, { key: 'angular', count: 13 } ], 
99:[ { key: 'javascript', count: 12 }, { key: 'typescript', count: 15 }, { key: 'angular', count: 13 } ], 
};

Object.keys(t).forEach(myNum => 
t[myNum].forEach(myObj => myObj.selected = false));

console.log(t);   ```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Array#Map`

```js
var items = [
{key:"javascript" , count : 12},
{key:"typescript", count: 15},
{key:"angular" , count: 13}
]

console.log(items.map(item=>({...item, selected: false})))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  [
    { key: 'javascript', count: 12 },
    { key: 'typescript', count: 15 },
    { key: 'angular', count: 13 }
  ]
];

data[0].forEach(item => (item.selected = false));

console.log(data);
```

Comment: i already did... :) ..under review I guess