# how to add values in in javascript object

Tags: javascript, object

I am getting object in response of axios/ajax request. Now i want to add key value pair in that object how i Can do this.

Here is the object

```
user: {id: 1, name: "swifty", email: "swift.solutions.com@gmail.com", avatar: null, email_verified_at: null,…}
```

I want to update this object and add one more key **is_customer**

This is how i tried But it assigned only one key value is_customer and removed all others

```
response.data.user = {'is_customer': is_customer}
```

Comment: `response.data.user.is_customer = is_customer`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
user.is_customer = is_customer;
```

or

```
user["is_customer"] = is_customer;
```

Both are the same thing, but make sure user itself is defined so that these two don't throw errors when ran.

user in this case can be any object.