# better way to add new property to existing object in another function on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

what is the best way to update add new property to existing object from another function via click event?

this is my existing method that already has object

```
function another() {
  $scope.baseProduct = {
    prop1: 'ABC',
    prop2: 'DEF',
    prop3: 'GHI',
    // need to add newProp: true through showEligibleOffer()
  }
}
```

i need to access `another()` in my `showEligibleOffer()` to add one more new property called 'newProp: true' if checkbox is checked,  otherwise newProp: false

so what I've done is

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="demo">
  <input type='checkbox' ng-click='showEligibleOffer($event)' ng-model='showOffer' />
  <p ng-if='showOffer'>
    hello
  </p>
</div>


$scope.showEligibleOffer = function(e) {
  $scope.showOffer = !$scope.showOffer;
  var evt = e.target.checked;

  if ($scope.showOffer) {
        $scope.baseProduct = {
          newProp: evt
        }
  }
  console.log('new prop', $scope.baseProduct);
}
```

when  do console.log after check and uncheck, not able to read $scope.baseProduct completly but instead its only showing like this

```
"new prop", {
  newProp: true
}
```

here I need help for below on

1. better way to add new property to existing object
2. pass true/false to that newly added property based on check and uncheck without duplicating the existing original object

[here my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sathya_da/90bnpq5g/33/)

Thanks for the help every one

Answer (score 0):

You can use destructuring assignment, like:

```
$scope.baseProduct = {
   ...$scope.baseProduct,
   newProp: evt
}
```

Or an older way is to add directly the new property into your object like:

```
$scope.baseProduct.newProp = evt;
```

Or using `Object.assign`:

```
Object.assign($scope.baseProduct, { newProp: evt })
```

Comment: Yes, it thought of that initially, but unfortunately, not working with latest es6 version

Comment: Object.assign() helping what i want. but still looking for any other better way

Comment: @Mr.Learner "but still looking for any other better way". I don't think there is any other way to do it. [cf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0):

you are only getting the newProp in console because the function `another` is not called before the ng-click function triggers. so you `$scope.baseProduct` is not yet available.

Since `$scope.baseProduct` is not available it is `undefined` and you cannot spread it using `...`

```js
angular.module("app", [])

  .controller("demo", function($scope) {
    

    function another() {
      $scope.baseProduct = {
        prop1: 'ABC',
        prop2: 'DEF',
        prop3: 'GHI',
        // need to add newProp: true through showEligibleOffer()
      }
    }
    
    // some one need to call this function
    // unless it is called $scope.baseProduct doesnt exist
    another()
    
    $scope.showEligibleOffer = function(e) {
      console.log('what is hre', e.target.checked)

      console.log('new prop', $scope.baseProduct);
      $scope.showOffer = !$scope.showOffer;
      var evt = e.target.checked;
      if ($scope.showOffer) {
        $scope.baseProduct = {
          ...$scope.baseProduct,
          newProp: evt
        }
      }
      console.log('new prop', $scope.baseProduct);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="demo">
  <input type='checkbox' ng-click='showEligibleOffer($event)' ng-model='showOffer' />
  <p ng-if='showOffer'>
    hello
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: currently not working with latest JS. and still in your solution it returns true though we unchecked the checkbox. i want the property to be true/ false when check/uncheck